# predefined cell ID assignment for an ad-hoc wlan

Tags: linux, adhoc, wireless

I have a debian/ubuntu boards that I connect them via an ad-hoc network with the following settings

```
board:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        wpa-driver nl80211
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

board:~# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
# IBSS/ad-hoc network with WPA-None/TKIP.
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1

network={
        ssid="adhoc_test"
        mode=1
        frequency=2412
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-NONE
        pairwise=NONE
        group=TKIP
        psk="abcdefgh"
        bssid=F8:D1:11:52:0C:4E
}
```

These configurations creates an ad-hoc wlan, however, the nodes often gets different cell ID so that they cannot communicate with each other. To prevent it I added `bssid=F8:D1:11:52:0C:4E` line, however, no node get this predefined cell ID when they get the cell ID.

**My question** is that how can I prevent nodes to get different cell IDs? why `bssid` line does not work in the ad-hoc mode?

P.S. I tried these settings on ubuntu and debian dist. that have 3.2 and 3.4 kernels. wpa_supplicant versions that I used were 0.7, 1.0, and 2.0 all did not work. For the chipset, I am using Atheros AR9271 chipset for the wifi module.

Comment: Try on superuser.com or askubuntu.com. Stackoverflow is about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was that previous versions of wpa_supplicant does not support the bssid, installing wpa_Supplicant 2.0 solved the problem!

Answer (score 5):

Use ap_scan=2 and remove the bssid= line from the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I answered same question at https://superuser.com/questions/552935/while-using-ad-hoc-networking-how-to-i-force-nodes-to-use-the-same-cell-ids-bs/569860#569860

Simple version: after ad-hoc configuration:

sudo iwconfig ath0 ap 11:22:33:44:55:66

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I wrote on superusers, I am looking for a solution for `wpa_supplicant`. I would appreciate a lot for a working solution for `wpa_supplicant`